how to get razorpay Order_id in flask app
when i am click on pay button in browser then show "order_id" is invailid
how to get proper unique order_id of every payment
index.html
<script>
var options = {

    "key": "##############", 
    "amount": "100", 

    "currency": "INR",
    "name": "Galaxy Point",

    "description": "Kharghar navi mumbai",
    "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
    "order_id": "{{order_id}}", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
    "callback_url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/payment",
    "theme": {
        "color": "#3799cc"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>

App.py
@app.route('/')
def index():
global payment
client = razorpay.Client(auth=("rzp_test_4TiW07UGuka131", "ds8fWK8gBhIYphLU0bwBCdau"))
data = { "amount": 100, "currency": "INR", "receipt": "#11" 
payment = client.order.create(data=data)
order_id = data
return render_template("index.html", payment=payment, order_id=order_d)


Is it possible that the problem is in the misspelling of order_d?
order_id=order_d


i just check this but cannot solve same error is here

@Manishkumar can you try this: order_id = payment['id'] instead of order_id = data ? Also replace "order_id": "{{order_id}}" with "order_id": order_id in your HTML code.
